# Kendo UI ASP.NET MVC wrapper licensing

Tags: telerik, licensing, kendo-ui

**Question:**

nopCommerce currently uses TelerikMVC Extensions which have server-side wrappers for client side code that is free to use for open source projects.

Is it correct that for Kendo UI (the replacement for TelerikMVC), only the client side libraries are available for open source projects, and NOT that server side wrappers?

**Remarks:**

If so, Telerik, this would burn the open source community. In terms of the server side wrappers, you have released one version that was open source friendly, and then replaced it with another product that is not. Not cool!

I would greatly like to update nopCommerce to use KendoUI but it would be too much work to manually do all the client side markup/scripting.

Hindsight is always 20/20. Ubmbraco 5, TelerikMVC, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Only Kendo UI Web is available under the GPL license. Kendo UI Complete for ASP.NET MVC is **not** available as open source.

You have two options:

1. Continue using Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC. If you don't need
   any features of Kendo UI you don't need to upgrade at all.
2. Use Kendo UI Web GPL. Yes, you would need to write JavaScript
   instead of C# code.